# Enter values into MySql Database based on PHP Name/Value pairs array

Tags: php, mysql, simplexml

I have the following array:

```
      SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
    [@attributes] => Array
    (
        [name] => Gallops
    )

[table] => Array
    (
        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Details
                    )

                [row] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [col] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 1
                                [1] => Ggvbbvhh
                                [2] => Vvb
                                [3] => Bnb
                                [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [@attributes] => Array
                                            (
                                                [name] => Owner
                                            )

                                    )

                                [5] => Marwari horse
                                [6] => Gender
                                [7] => 16-May-2013
                                [8] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [@attributes] => Array
                                            (
                                                [name] => Notes
                                            )

                                    )

                                [9] => Nature
                                [10] => Color
                                [11] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [@attributes] => Array
                                            (
                                                [name] => Sire
                                            )

                                    )

                                [12] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [@attributes] => Array
                                            (
                                                [name] => Dam
                                            )

                                    )

                                [13] => 0.0hh
                                [14] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [@attributes] => Array
                                            (
                                                [name] => Foaled
                                            )

                                    )

                                [15] => 16-May-2013
                                [16] => null
                            )

                    )

            )

        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Vaccination
                    )

                [row] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [col] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 1
                                [1] => Pending
                                [2] => Ggvbbvhh
                                [3] => Rabies
                                [4] => 16-5-2013 
                                [5] => 17:22
                            )

                    )

            )

        [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => DeWorming
                    )

                [row] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [col] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 1
                                [1] => Pending
                                [2] => Ggvbbvhh
                                [3] => Large strongyles
                                [4] => 16-5-2013 
                                [5] => 17:22
                            )

                    )

            )

        [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Weight
                    )

                [row] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [col] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 1
                                [1] => Ggvbbvhh
                                [2] =>  32.27lbs
                                [3] => 2013-05-16
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

)
     @attributes => Array
     row => 
     @attributes => Array
     row => 
     @attributes => Array
     row => 
     @attributes => Array
     row =>
```

I am looking for a script which helps me insert these values into an already existing and matching DB on mySql.

Here ~~~> Gallops is the DB name, Details, Vaccination, Deworming and Weight are the tables.

This is my PHP Script from where I get the above values after I pass it an XML file.

```
              <?php
              echo "<pre>";   
              $xml = simplexml_load_file("DB355404040101391.xml");
                  print_r($xml);
                  echo "</pre>";
                  echo "<pre>";
                  foreach($xml->children() as $item){
                      $arr = get_object_vars($item);
                      foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
                          echo "$key => $value" . PHP_EOL;            
                      }
                  }
                  echo "</pre>"; 
              ?>
```

Here is the XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <database name='anahuacForm'>
     <table name='Details'>
      <row>
        <col name='_id'>1</col>
        <col name='IDno'>Ggvbbvhh</col>
        <col name='GIDno'>Vvb</col>
        <col name='Name'>Bnb</col>
        <col name='Owner'></col>
        <col name='Breed'>Marwari horse</col>
        <col name='Gender'>Gender</col>
        <col name='Date'>16-May-2013</col>
        <col name='Notes'></col>
        <col name='Nature'>Nature</col>
        <col name='Color'>Color</col>
        <col name='Sire'></col>
        <col name='Dam'></col>
        <col name='Height'>0.0hh</col>
        <col name='Foaled'></col>
        <col name='Acquired'>16-May-2013</col>
        <col name='image'>null</col>
    </row>
</table>
<table name='Vaccination'>
    <row>
        <col name='_id'>1</col>
        <col name='flag'>Pending</col>
        <col name='HVID'>Ggvbbvhh</col>
        <col name='Vname'>Rabies</col>
        <col name='Vdate'>16-5-2013 </col>
        <col name='Vtime'>17:22</col>
    </row>
</table>
<table name='DeWorming'>
    <row>
        <col name='_id'>1</col>
        <col name='flag'>Pending</col>
        <col name='DVID'>Ggvbbvhh</col>
        <col name='Dname'>Large strongyles</col>
        <col name='Ddate'>16-5-2013 </col>
        <col name='Dtime'>17:22</col>
    </row>
</table>
<table name='Weight'>
    <row>
        <col name='_id'>1</col>
        <col name='HWID'>Ggvbbvhh</col>
        <col name='Wmeasure'> 32.27lbs</col>
        <col name='WDate'>2013-05-16</col>
    </row>
</table>
```

I can go for a simple way too, where in I can directly enter XML to MYSql. I need a starting point or a solution. Will be much appreciated.

Comment: Update XML it'll be too good to get answer instead of debug syntax

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution posted here:
 http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?258036-RESOLVED-XML-to-MySql-Using-PHP

[http://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/PHP_-*MySQL*-_XML_tutorial_-_basics](http://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/PHP_-_MySQL_-_XML_tutorial_-_basics)